# Clear TextField From Another Class

Tags: java, javafx

In my main FXML controller class Alpha I have a mask with a text field and a button the clear it:

```
@FXML
private TextField testTF = new TextField();

@FXML
public void clearText() {
    if (testTF != null)
    testTF.clear();
}
```

If I enter text in to the text field and hit the clear button, the text is being removed. So far, all good.

I have a second controller class Beta. The corresponding fxml file contains the menu layout (menu bar). If the menu item "new" is clicked, it should also clear my text field in class Alpha.

```
public class Beta {
    private void newApp() {
        Alpha a = new Alpha();
        a.clear();
    }
}
```

Nothing happens though. What am I doing wrong here? How can I click a button/menu item in a FXML controller class and have it to clear a text field in another FXML controller class?

Comment: You are creating a new object `Alpha`, so you cannot create something from the *existing one*. I am sure that you did clear from this new object but it isn't probably the one you were trying to clear.

Comment: @Kyllopardiun thanks. that's what i figured. thanks to Forager's help I was able to resolve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not instantiate testTF with `new TextField();`: FXMLLoader will automatically assign `testTF` the corresponding `TextField` object because you have a @FXML tag.

You're re-instantiating `Alpha` in class `Beta`, which exists separately from the one which was created when your fxml was loaded, resulting in two separate `private TextField testTF` objects. Either give `Beta` a reference to the first instance of `Alpha`, or try this alternative:

```
    public class Alpha implements Initializable {

        public static TextField tf;

        @FXML
        private TextField testTF;

        @Override
        public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
            tf = testTF;
        }
    }

    public class Beta {
        private void newApp() {
            if (Alpha.tf != null)
                Alpha.tf.clear();
        }
    }
```

Comment: thank you so much! your alternative works like a charm. would it be easier to do with a reference to the other class, if I'd have to do it for multiple text fields? how would I do this? I have not used references in javafx so far. minor syntax correction in your code: it's "clear()" and not "clearText()".

Comment: Oh, you used clear() in Alpha and clearText() in beta. If you really want to give a reference to your whole class you could make `public static Alpha instance;` and use `instance = this` in your initialize method, or build `ArrayList<TextField>` or `ArrayList<Node>` depending on your needs.

Comment: thanks again! I got it all working now. I've added the code for the reference example to your post.